# Java map replace one-ot-one

Tags: java, regex, replace

For example, I have a String `"PARAMS @ FOO @ BAR @"` and String array `{"one", "two", "three"}`.

How would you map the array values one-to-one to the string (replace the markers), so that in the end I would get: `"PARAMS one, FOO two, BAR three"`.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do

```
String str =  "PARAMS @ FOO @ BAR @";
String[] arr = {"one", "two", "three"};

for (String s : arr)
    str = str.replaceFirst("@", s);
```

After this, `str` would hold `"PARAMS one FOO two BAR three"`. Of course, to include the commas you could just replace with `s + ","`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way: -

```
    String str = "PARAMS @ FOO @ BAR @";
    String[] array = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
    String[] original = str.split("@");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        builder.append(original[i]).append(array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Note - very useful method  in class String: [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). It helps to solve your problem very laconically:

```
String str = "PARAMS @ FOO @ BAR @";
String repl = str.replaceAll( "@", "%s" ); // "PARAMS %s FOO %s BAR %s"
String result = String.format( repl, new Object[]{ "one", "two", "three" }); 
// result is "PARAMS one FOO two BAR three"
```